# Smart contract AST extraction through solidity-parser

Tags: python, parsing, solidity, smartcontracts

Iam receiving this error

> File "", line 2
> python3 -m solidity_parser <parse|outline> https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

while trying to extract solidity smart contract AST,I wrote the following code

> pip install solidity-parser
> python3 -m solidity_parser  < parse > https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

I used the following link for guidance https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The angle brackets ( `< >` ) indicate that the enclosed element (parameter, value, or information) is mandatory. You are required to replace the text within the angle brackets with the appropriate information. Do not type the angle brackets themselves in the command line.

In your case, you can try below commands in the terminal.

```bash
pip install solidity-parser
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol
python3 -m solidity_parser parse ERC721.sol
```